# How do I convert multiple nested values into categorical variables using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categorical-data

I'm working on the yelp data set and for businesses, this is the first line of json that comes from `yelp_academic_dataset_business.json`. Subsequent lines match this schema:

```
{
  "business_id":"0DI8Dt2PJp07XkVvIElIcQ",
  "name":"Innovative Vapors",
  "neighborhood":"",
  "address":"227 E Baseline Rd, Ste J2",
  "city":"Tempe",
  "state":"AZ",
  "postal_code":"85283",
  "latitude":33.3782141,
  "longitude":-111.936102,
  "stars":4.5,
  "review_count":17,
  "is_open":0,
  "attributes":[
    "BikeParking: True",
    "BusinessAcceptsBitcoin: False",
    "BusinessAcceptsCreditCards: True",
    "BusinessParking: {
      'garage': False,
      'street': False,
      'validated': False,
      'lot': True,
      'valet': False
    }",
    "DogsAllowed: False",
    "RestaurantsPriceRange2: 2",
    "WheelchairAccessible: True"
  ],
  "categories": [
    "Tobacco Shops",
    "Nightlife",
    "Vape Shops",
    "Shopping"
  ],
  "hours":[
    "Monday 11:0-21:0",
    "Tuesday 11:0-21:0",
    "Wednesday 11:0-21:0",
    "Thursday 11:0-21:0",
    "Friday 11:0-22:0",
    "Saturday 10:0-22:0",
    "Sunday 11:0-18:0"
  ],
  "type":"business"
}
```

I tried to parse the json to a csv and import the csv using `pd.read_csv` and I get the following DF:

```
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|idx|                     attributes                                  |
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| 0 | BikeParking: True, BusinessAcceptsBitcoin: False,               |
|   | BusinessAcceptsCreditCards: True, ,DogsAllowed: False,          |
|   | RestaurantsPriceRange2: 2, WheelchairAccessible: True,          |
|   | BusinessParking: {'garage': False,                              |
|   |                   'street': False,                              |
|   |                   'validated': False,                           |
|   |                   'lot': True,                                  |
|   |                   'valet': False}                               |
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But what I really want is something like:

```
+----+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| id | attributes_BusinessParking_garage | attributes_BusinessParking_lot    |
+----+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
|  0 |                  1                |                0                  |
+----+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
```

I know there is `pd.get_dummies` but since the cell is treated as a string, I don't get nice flat categorical columns

Note: There are more columns that I have not  shown in the example for simplicity.

Comment: Did the data come in like that or is this after your import? Please show original data source and import.

Comment: This is how the data came in.

Comment: Forgive me, but Yelp did not hand over a pandas dataframe. Did it originate as json? csv? xml?

Comment: Ohh. It's handed out as a json file and I used this to parse to a csv https://gist.github.com/paulgb/5265767

Comment: Please post a sample of original json as pandas has I/O methods to import such files, not used in link code.

Comment: updated to show original json format.

Comment: Forgive me again and I really do want to help but your json is not valid. Check [online validators](https://www.google.com/#q=json+validator&*). Quotes are in the wrong place, single quotes are included, square brackets are not holding curly brace collections, and true/false needs to be lower case. Is this really the actual Yelp output?

Comment: yes. that is the actual yelp dataset unfortunately :( The attributes and hours fields are kind of a nightmare

Comment: Very strange a reputable company like Yelp sends over invalid json with its API. I have a pandas solution that works for a valid json. Don't know if it will help much with this raw format.

Comment: It's not via their api. it's from https://www.yelp.com/dataset_challenge. They package that as a zip file

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a map function to separate the attributes.

You may want to initialize the columns you want to empty strings or whatever data type you want and then do something like:

```
def split_attributes (row):
    for k, v in row[0].items():
        row[k] = v
df = df.apply(split_attributes)
```

**EDIT**

Based on your updated question; have you tried using `pd.read_json`?

Comment: the json is not treated as a dictionary by pandas in this case. It's stored as a string. I also have to handle a case where the structure is nested.

Comment: Why not convert the string to a dictionary? Are you familiar with the `ast` module? I realize its not the most efficient solution in terms of time, but if it gets you where you want to be...